# ReadyAPI : Add some script to the "Setup script" at the TestSuite level of ProjectB using groovy script in ProjectA

Tags: groovy, automation, scripting, soapui, ready-api

[image]This requirement is for Automating the project/testsuite/testcase creation in ReadyAPI. I would like to know if there is a way to add groovy script in the Setup script of the TestSuite of ProjectB using a groovy script from ProjectA.

I tried researching and couldn't find a valid class in the ReadyAPI documentation to do this.

I referred the below documentation.
https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/apidocs/soapui/overview-summary.html

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/nmrao/sample-soapui-projects/tree/master/addSetupTeardownScript) which is adding to the test case. So you will get an idea to add to test suite.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to share scripts between projects is to use the [Script Library](https://www.soapui.org/docs/scripting-and-properties/scripting-and-the-script-library/#2-Groovy-Script-Library).

The gist of it is:

- All scripts must be placed in a common location, by default `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/scripts`.
- Each script is placed in sub-folders depending on the script's `package`. Each script is named same as the `class` name.
- These will be added to the classpath of SoapUI, and refreshed every 5 seconds. See SoapUI log to make sure things are working correctly.